# New IE 8 instances/tabs won't load website

Tags: internet-explorer-8, multiple-instances

I'm having issues with IE8. Most of the time I can only have one active window. If I open a new window or another tab with the "new" button (either window or tab), the status gets stuck at "waiting for http://..." and IE8 doesn't continue loading the website. The window that was opened first works perfectly fine though.

Firefox also works fine so I'm assuming it has something to do with IE8. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have this same problem. Any pop-up or new tab from a link on an existing page never loads. The icon on the tab spins, but the page remains blank. I reset all browser settings, but the problem persists. IE works under other profiles on the same machine (Windows 7).

Answer (score 2):

Does it work if you use IE8 under another profile? also you could try the reset all settings button in ie8 options and failing that a repair/reinstall

Also it could be worth checking what addonds are loaded, maybe one of them is tripping something up.

Comment: I did have the IE7 developer toolbar installed so maybe that's messing with IE8.  I'll try to reset the settings later today. I don't know why I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered that if I start IE8 using "Run as administrator," the problem with new tabs and pop-up browser instances stalling goes away. This is on Windows 7 where I am logged-in with an account that is already in the Administrators group, so I'm not sure why the additional "Run as administrator" step would be needed, but it works around whatever the underlying issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Tools, Internet Options, Connections, LAN Settings: make sure that "Automatically detect settings" is not checked if you don't use a proxy server.

Comment: It is unchecked.  Right now I can use multiple tabs/windows.  Sometimes I can, sometimes I can't.